# Compiling DISLIN gfortran

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran

I am having trouble compiling Fortran code with references to [DISLIN](http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/). I have downloaded DISLIN from the website, unzipped the file and ran the setup. I have added an environment variable called DISLIN (C:\dislin) and added C:\dislin\win to the `PATH` section of my system variables.

I am trying to compile some example code of the DISLIN website which includes line

```
USE DISLIN
```

I am using a MinGW shell to compile with command `gfortran -o progrname -ldislin EX11_1.f90` and am getting the following error:

> Fatal Error: Cant open module file 'dislin.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory.

I have tried changing the variable path and even moving the `dislin.mod` file (which is there) but still get the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I fixed this problem so thought I come back and post what worked for me incase any one else needs it...

1. Install both DISLIN and MinGW on the c drive
2. Copy disgf.a from /c/dislin and dislin.f90 from /c/dislin/gf into the directory containing your fortran files
   (for me this is /c/MinGW/pnote)
3. Using the MinGW shell navigate to you files: `cd /c/MinGW/pnote`
4. compile dislin.f90 and your fortran program: `gfortran -c dislin.f90 progName.f90` (dislin.f90 obviously only needs to be done once)
5. link libraries etc and compile: `gfortran progName.o disgf.a -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -o exeName`
6. 'run' exeName

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify the path to the DISLIN module files:

```
gfortran EX11_1.f90 -o progrname -ldislin -I/path/to/DISLIN/modules
```

and, if not already configured like described [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_External_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW), also the path to the library itself:

```
gfortran EX11_1.f90 -o progrname -ldislin -I/path/to/DISLIN/modules \
         -L/path/to/DISLIN/library
```

Comment: Great thanks, the files will now compile, however a new error is now showing. it says "undefined reference to 'subroutine_title'" for every sub routine that is being called in EX11_1. I have checked and  they are being called as defined in the dislin module. Any ideas on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

They provide a batch file (windows) to do the compiling and linking for you.

```
f90link -c My_Program
```

This is located in c:\dislin\Win

Also, if you are having trouble with the dislin.mod file which resides in c:\dislin\gf then recompile that with the -c compile option.  I found all of this info in c:\dislin\readme.inf

Answer (score 0):

near as I can tell (Jan 2018) dislin (64 bit) fails miserably with gfortran 7.2, period; and probably with many other newer compilers.
When trying to link, gfortran 7 says 'dislin.mod' is an unrecognizable format.
I think this program is highly dependent on exactly correct version synchronization - something that renders such software useless imho after many years in research.

and no, the correctness of various 'paths' seems not to help.

after all, gnuplot works, "at all". Not sure why I spent so much time on brand x.
jrc

Comment: If you use pre-compiled module files, you MUST use the same compiler and the same version as was used to generate the module file. It does not matter whether you use Gfortran 7.2, Intel 18 or xyz version 42, you MUST use the the same compiler that was used for the pre-compiled library.

Comment: That means that you must compile any header defining the module (probably `displin.f90`  according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19390203/721644 and re-compile it with the same compiler that you will use for your programs.